# moveMouse() selenium gives error

Tags: php, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I have used selenium 2.53.3 with nodejs.
to move mouse to particular button I have used
`mouseMove(elem)` function. ex:

```
driver.actions().mouseMove(elem).click().perform();
```

Some time it works and some time it not, what is the matter.

Some time I have got following error:

> POST /session/67809eeb-fa66-489d-84de-ab8426e6c796/moveto did not match a known command Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700' System info: host: '185-129-70-172', ip: '185.129.70.172', os.name: 'windows', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.8.0_101' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, browserstack.selenium.jar.version=3.0.1, appBuildId=20161104212021, moz:firefoxOptions={args=[], profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAKQ4MEoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHAAAAdXNlci5qc51Xy27jNhTd9ysKr1qgZpNJZ9Ou0kwGKDBoinGDWRIUeWUxpkiWD8v++15S0vilh52VJZnkfZ1z72H04Kh1UP60KJxp8I14VkJ+lnpNaqYa5oCAZoUCsfjlx5IpDz//8UM87BQs4BprXEhbKmAqVO07wUVbyWf295YrUBbco7WeaNjik9+gN1v413ySfoN7F8xaJTkL0uhfd8rvFqcHaQiNcRtShWCJraSv9sv0t2XeLxXodajwlA8fPw7bd8AE/ggIwAOIz9L58IhBcQW4Lbh4HrepMUE7yitnaqCeO2kDdVHTIOu05eFu2FBghSeYV/2in5TxMJ0WYRqtDBNoS7N1qlBlmm8V6BWmPaV8eLtFp2zwyRitjWBqpoiwDcYoT8A547jR3qjjul2G7+VaG41Zq6EuwK3yq5+OxYP3WDwfDILKgY+YtxIdpdwxX90OD2NBf5a5PnPg6I9RUrf7KOwCOM1UwsTNiC4TOr5GPexzA4VwEp2kjHNAVESNCfSIKsrBhZksCemtYnsQz/d3q78NIjAF+NvwYvwkXvQ3qREn/v6OSLRkXr9+ySkpTAy/F4rpzeISu21ElClF3zxmIzkq2xJeVntnJZYN15KmkgGU9AEP+C9KN4aoBKeNDKRjZY9eDC5hatDI9xoxrAwSaRqyPuE/WlIh+yyeTRtQPDExulTTxVnIqdw6o49EixUGojG15f4Vl4wYAB6dDPvMVbqV0CAcaC13IDIJqdF8hLwTCIo2sfl5MrLecInYxifig5M8UOPkWmpqDQJ9P40hDQ0yn3SpmADCiaPtySR9XMWilpmt/+SPjxnI182AwWMmI/7eILqapnriypEGeuAwhtlk6F+S2JQlroMlSx0DgYv1KvZUQMmiCsMdrU8797aD3jXAAI1oTchogG2GN1xibxLZPXWQZ9hdg9uTtpvn9R/m1k6TZtj1/BnmUN3n//n1yyN5IOwAictkvrEta0fi5BQ5L3xP5mnUXgbt4C1P7UkjLSnS8bckSQHbXp+jo1KzGJJ0SYZWHOGaOuv93dikaD2iGifYFihOOB2GW/GAjHhBLsy6UyjDN7lxvzv4m/vknBxgjlcdJeZUUE1aphMRazuJKWT8VTQ7gbPBGjgphgfTRUM+78QPw0q0HXrLvhUhyEOcGf7d2pE220nOea15pEB8llkHBYLtOOaRN5m5BN5hJ46YbVrFkDnxl35qVePgySfaHENYosTUyNi0fYm6bpmEVfbqnCGTHWs8TZ3OoHlMiJj3pMF7c0e/til6FKiK8Ar45lM7ZP5s/7ldvRAmhEypYTPTe/DS9t7LmjLrdfrYif/JeX3UVnLETziesHEVUqUkarmughpRKKep9kkfBIricqKeR9Z6J98zU2jPcVLjDSRzbJFuLWh2TOymSw5yFq8qM2r30NJU6aNtld5Bh/4PUEsHCEpq6ooxBAAAaQ8AAFBLAQIUABQACAgIAKQ4MEpKauqKMQQAAGkPAAAHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB1c2VyLmpzUEsFBgAAAAABAAEANQAAAGYEAAAAAA==}, platform=XP, specificationLevel=0, browserstack.video.disableWaterMark=true, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=492, browserstack.key=ShpoHTMYgjRnvvprcvm4, browser=firefox, browserVersion=50.0, platformVersion=6.2, acceptSslCert=false, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, browser_version=50.0, platformName=windows_nt, 64bit=true, browserstack.debug=false, rotatable=false, browserstack.ie.noFlash=false, firefoxOptions={args=[], profile=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}, browserstack.user=jasontownesfrenc1, version=50.0, proxy={}, command_id=1, firefox_binary=c:\Program Files (x86)\firefox 50.0\firefox.exe, browserstack.video=true, orig_os=win8, takesElementScreenshot=true, firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAAIAJgwMEoAAAAAAAAAA..., proxy_type=node}] Session ID: 67809eeb-fa66-489d-84de-ab8426e6c796

Comment: I got this today actually - turns out Firefox driver (gecko) doesn't support it yet, you'll need to use chromedriver.

Comment: can we use firefox specifix version for  -
driver.actions().mouseMove(elem).click().perform();

or is it totally wate of time to use it with firefox?

Comment: @Farkie can you please tell me, is there any solution with firefox!

Comment: No idea, I just changed to get it to work.

Comment: Hey @Farkie, I got one thing.....just change your firefox browser_version to 47. It will work!